# Do Gelatin Crystals have fixed spawn points? Or am I just (un)lucky that they seem to be respawning in the same places?

Tags: terraria

Do Gelatin Crystals have fixed spawn points? Or am I just (un)lucky that they seem to be respawning in the same places?

I seem to have seen one spot have it three times? But I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Wiki page](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Gelatin_Crystal), it is a random chance for the Gelatin Crystal to spawn on Pearlstone or Pink Ice Blocks. There is a 2% chance that any crystal that spawns will turn into a Gelatin Crystal. It would seem you may be lucky in it respawning in the same place.

Comment: I would like to see the Source Code for it, not sure how the Wiki knows what the code is, when it cites the code...

Comment: Not sure you're ever going to get source code. The wiki is trustworthy though, and I while I don't have the time to test their math on things I've used it for, I still believe it's trustworthy. Regardless of the percent chance, the Gelatinous Crystal replaces regular crystal growth on some low chance.